# Ocaml : using records and variants in argument types

Tags: ocaml, record, variant, bucklescript

As a newbie in Ocaml, I'm playing with type and try to understand how variants work.

Here is the sample :

```
type 'a component =
  { foo : int;
    bar : 'a }

type string_or_float_component =
  | Str of string component
  | Flt of float component

let get_foo_1 (comp: 'a component) = comp.foo
(* works *)

let get_foo_2 (Str comp) = comp.foo
(* works *)

let get_bar_3 (comp : string_or_float_component) = comp.foo
(* This expression has type string_or_float_component
   but an expression was expected of type 'a component *)
```

I'm not try to find the best solution (like pattern matching), just understand why ocaml can't infers in the get_bar_3 that component is Str | Flt.

Maybe that kind of trick is someway possible ?

```
type 'a string_or_float =
  | Str of string 'a
  | Flt of float 'a
```

Thanks

(I'm using bucklescript)

**Edit :**

Realised that my problem is more design related. I could work with something like this :

```
type string_or_float  =
    | Str of string
    | Flt of float


type 'a component = { foo: int; bar: 'a }

let get_bar_3 (comp : string_or_float component) ...
```

Comment: I think you have add pattern matching into you function, I guess OCaml designers were more concerned with developing faster more most practical cases compiler, than smartest. But could be some dogma of strictly typed programming (were Str and Flt kind of monads or smth)

Comment: may be chapter on Explicit Polymorphism annotations could clarify it for you? https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/polymorphism.html

Comment: Thanks you Serge, I'll gonna check this !

Answer (score 3):

In the expression `let get_bar_3 (comp : string_or_float_component)` , `comp` is an enumerated type : either a `Str of something` or a `Flo of something`.
In any case, `comp` is not a record type at that point, only `something` is a record type.

To extract the field from `something` :

```
 let get_bar_3 (comp : string_or_float_component) = let Str a = comp in a.foo;;
```

Which will give a warning at compile type.
The complete code is rather this one :

```
 let get_bar_3 (comp : string_or_float_component) = match comp with
  | Str a -> a.foo
  | Flt a -> a.foo;;
```

Comment: Thanks you ! I I wondered since a variant could contains everything, it doesn't garantee that all its constructors shares the same structure.

Comment: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual006.html section 4.2 exposes the problematic I encounter. Lets see how that magic works !